# Integer solutions to $x^3 + 3x^2y - 3xy^2 - 3y^3 = 1$

Tags: diophantine-equations

Prove that the only integer solutions to $x^3 + 3x^2y - 3xy^2 - 3y^3 = 1$ are $(1,0)$ and $(-2,3)$.

My only idea for now is to try to represent this in the form $A^3 + B^3 = C^3$ and apply Fermat's Last Theorem. However, I cannot find suitable $A,B,C$.

It is also easy to see that firstly $x\equiv 1 \pmod 3$ and then $3$ divides $y$, but substituting does not give a better looking equation.

Another alternative: if we set $s = x+y$, then we get $s^3 -6sy^2 + 2y^3 = 1$ which looks a bit better.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Dividing everything by $y^3$ looks nice but I haven't been able to get anywhere.

Comment: This Thue equation. In pari/gp `thue(x^3+3*x^2-3*x-3,1)`, then output `[[-2, 3], [1, 0]]`.

Comment: Ok but that is cheating.  Any idea how such things are proven?

Comment: @DesmondMiles, x=-2, y=3 does not satisfy the equation, so the statement of question is wrong. the only solution is x=1 and y=0.

Comment: @sirous x=-2, y=3 does satisfy the equation

Comment: @DesmondMiles xould you provide more context?

Comment: Maybe could be useful to write the given equation in this equivalent form: $\,(s-1)\cdot(s^2+s+1)=2y^2(3s-y)$, with $\,s=x+y$. Clearly, if $\,s\,$ is even the equation has no solution. So, we can define $\,k=\frac{s-1}2\,$ and write the equation as $\,k(3+6k+4k^2)=y^2(3+6k-y)\,$.

Comment: @DesmondMiles, the equation can be written as $(x+3y)(x^2-3y^2)=1-6y^3$,If y=3 then RHS can be factorized as $3^4--3^4)(3^4-1+3^4)=-1(2\times 3^4-1)=-161=(7)(-23)$, which gives $x=2$. If $x=1$ it can  easily  be seen that y=0.